# EDGE does not support property disabled of style elements

Tags: styles, microsoft-edge

We discovered recently a "glitch" in the newish browser **EDGE** (Windows 10).
We are using multiple *style* elements to dynamcally change the look&feel of our web-application, e.g.:

```
<style id="st1"></style>
<style id="st2"></style>
<style id="st3"></style>
```

At runtime we control the validity of the different styles (via javascript) by changing the *disabled* property of those *style* emelemts:

```
document.getElementById("st2").disabled=true
```

So far so good, but our first steps in **EDGE** (Windows 10 default-browser) showed up some awful styles... It seems that the new engine does not support the changing of *disabled* property - of *style* elements - anymore. It always validates *all* styles and therefore the latest definitions are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Our first (best) workaround for this scenario (our scenario, see above) is to manipulate the *media* property (attribute) of the *style* elements, e.g.:

```
<!-- empty value -->
document.getElementById("st2").media=''
<!-- or 'fantasy'-value -->
document.getElementById("st2").media='disabled'
```

Now the design/style shows up nicely as before :)

EDIT: To re-enable *style* elements "this way" one should do:

```
document.getElementById("st2").media='all'

<!-- sample snippet -->
if( configuration.processLayoutStyle == item.id ) {
    item.dom.disabled = false;   // old-fashioned
    item.dom.media = 'all';      // "our" workaround
    this.application.processLayoutStyle = configuration.processLayoutStyle;
} else {
    item.dom.disabled = true;    // old-fashioned
    item.dom.media = 'disabled'; // "our" workaround
}
```